# A better formula for derivative of determinant

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

I need to evaluate the derivative of the function $X \mapsto \operatorname{det}X$, where $X$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix. I already proved that if $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a $p$-linear map, then:
$$f'(x_{1},...,x_{p})(h_{1},...,h_{p}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{1},...,x_{i-1},h_{i},x_{i+1},...,x_{p}).$$
Since $\operatorname{det}X$ is an $n$-linear map of its rows $\varphi_{1},...,\varphi_{n}$, $\varphi_{i}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, it follows immediately from the last expression that, if $f(X) = \operatorname{det}X$ and $H$ is some $n\times n$ real matrix with rows $h_{1},...,h_{n}$:
$$f'(X)H = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\operatorname{det}(X|_{h_{i}})$$
where I denoted by $X|_{h_{i}}$ the $X$ matrix with the $i$-th row replaced by $h_{i}$.

So, my question is: is there another way to express $f'(X)H$? I think there must be some nicer way to express it, so to get some sort of formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the formula you got, for $X = I_n$ the identity, you get :
$$\text df(I_n)H = \operatorname{Tr}( H)$$

Then, for $X$ an invertible matrix, you have :
\begin{align}
f(X+H) &= \det(X+H) \\
&= \det(X)\det(I_n+X^{-1}H) \\
&= \det(X) \Big( 1+\operatorname{Tr}(X^{-1}H) + o(\|H\|)\Big)
\end{align}
and therefore :
$$\text d f(X)H = \det(X)\operatorname{Tr}(X^{-1}H) = \operatorname{Tr}(\operatorname{Cof}(X)H)$$

where $\operatorname{Cof}(X)$ is the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Cofactor_expansion_of_the_determinant) of $X$. Since it is polynomial in the coefficient of $X$, the last formula extends by continuity to any matrix $X$.